# AFNetworking (iOS) - response is not NSDictionary

Tags: ios, web-services, afnetworking

I know my request is formatted properly, but the response I get from the web service is not an NSDictionary.

1. Why would it not be an NSDictionary?
2. How can I tell what kind of object "responseObject" is?

   ```
   AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFParseAPIClient sharedClient]  HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
           NSLog(@"Response for %@: %@", className, responseObject);
           [self writeJSONResponse:responseObject toDiskForClassWithName:className];
       }else{
           //NSLog(@"Response NOT NSDictionary: %@", [responseObject class]);
           NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
       }
   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Request for class %@ failed with error: %@", className, error);
   }];
   ```

Here's what I get:

```
//Response NOT NSDictionary: <7b227265 73756c74 73223a5b 7b22636f ...>
```

EDIT: here's what I get back:

```
str: {"results":[{"desc":"My description.","device_iPad":true,"device_iPhone":true,"createdAt":"2012-09-05T18:36:11.431Z","updatedAt":"2012-09-05T22:00:52.199Z"}]}
```

Comment: `[responseObject class]` will tell you what it is. Could it be just a string?

Comment: Well that answers part 2 of my question: __NSCFData. But I'm supposed to be getting an NSDictionary...

Comment: Perhaps the service is returning an error. Try the NSString method `- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` and print your string and see what it contains.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Can you give an example that would work with the responseObject above?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this will work, just throwing ideas out :p .. Try `NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: Thanks! See my edit above. The data looks fine right? I'm supposed to be looking for a dictionary...

Comment: Your JSON is valid, [here's](http://jsonlint.com/) a useful link to test it.

Comment: The dictionary you are looking for is inside an array named `results`

Comment: Actually it looks like what I get back is a dictionary with one key/value pair. The key should be "results" right? Why isn't this a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be useful to you? It's from AFNetworking [github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) project

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gowalla.com/users/mattt.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperationJSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
NSLog(@"Name: %@ %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"first_name"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"last_name"]);
} failure:nil];

[operation start];
```

Give it a try, it's pretty straightforward. *If it's still an array do `[[JSON objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey@"desc /*(or whatever)*/"]`

Comment: How can I get the dictionary inside the "results" array?

Comment: [responseObject valueForKey:@"results"] , [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"results"], [responseObject objectAtIndex:0] all give errors

Comment: Did you use the method in my answer, could you post the resulting JSON object, and what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I have AFNetworking, but I get this: Use of undeclared identifier AFJSONRequestOperationJSONRequestOperationWithRequest

Comment: @soleil seperate `AFJSONRequestOperationJSONRequestOperationWithRequest` to `AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest`

Comment: It´s Working..  I´ve also missed the [operation start]

Here it´s a cool tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Answer (score 4):

just add this line of code after creating your operation

**operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];**

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem but performing requests with a subclass of AFHTTPClient. I was getting a __NSCFData instead of a __NSCFDictionary. I solved it with this:

```
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

self is my AFHTTPClient subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Use AFJSONRequestOperation and AFNetworking returns a JSON response. Using AFHTTPRequestOperation returns NSData which you can convert (cast) to NSDictionary and print using the following:

NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

My advice is to just use AFJSONRequestOperation!